# jQuery link not fired

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to load some ajax Content, but whenever i click on the link jQuery does not respond.

Heres my html with jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="e3.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img src='img/site/loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";

//  load() functions

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#omtA").click(function()
    {
    var loadUrl = "fomt.php";

    $("#usr")
        .html(ajax_load)
        .load(loadUrl, "fid=<?php echo $fid;?>");
    }

);
);
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="page">

<div id="content">
    <div id="up">
        <div id="tab">
              <ul id="tabmenu">
            <li id="anm" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Anm</span></a></li>
            <li id="kom" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Kom</span></a></li>

            <li id="omt" class="tbs blue"><a href="#usrl" id="omtA"><span>Omt</span></a></li>
            <li id="sts" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Sts</span></a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="usrp">
        <a name="usrl"></a>
        <div id="usr">
            hans
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="bottom">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the the Omt link with the id omtA nothing happends.

I have also tried

```
$("a#omtA").click(function()
```

make the link a class and tried

```
$(".omtA").click(function()
```

and

```
$("a.omtA").click(function()
```

But none of that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this.. You have missed the closing brace } ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#omtA").click(function() {
        var loadUrl = "fomt.php";
        $("#usr")
            .html(ajax_load)
            .load(loadUrl, "fid=<?php echo $fid;?>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but I must have missed something, I'am pretty sure I tried }); at some point.                                                              Thank You

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/05/javascript-click-here-to-make-default.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing an ending brace:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#omtA").click(function() {
      var loadUrl = "fomt.php";

       $("#usr")
        .html(ajax_load)
        .load(loadUrl, "fid=<?php echo $fid;?>");
    });
}/* <- that brace was missing */);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but I must have missed something, I'am pretty sure I tried }); at some point. Thank You